# Python extending decimals

Tags: python

Why is it that python sometimes extends numbers and is there a way to stop it? For example 1.7 may turn into 1.70000005.
Specifically I'm encountering this while taking in a list of floats and trying to populate a new list.

```
newList = []
for value in myList:
    print value
    newList.append(value)
return newList
```

The console will print out numbers containing no more than 2 decimal places while the newList being returned will have 17 places and oftentimes include a non-zero in the last digit. It does this even if I attempt to round(value,2) inside the loop.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is a heartless mistress :)

Comment: If you need exact floating point control, use the built in decimal module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: or fractions! http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Comment: This is a fundamental property of binary floating point - not every decimal value can be represented exactly. You just need to learn to live with it, or as suggested use something other than a `float` to store those values.

Comment: Thanks all for the fast responses.

Comment: `1.1+2.2=3.3000000000000003` O My!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the representation! Actually, the contents of the list is still the same.

To show it properly, you can format it in a string:

```
print("{.17f}".format(my_float_value))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `decimals` module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> my_float = decimal.Decimal("0.2342134235")
>>> my_float
Decimal('0.2342134235')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

CPython uses C doubles, and C doubles are typically implemented in hardware for speed.

Hardware floating point is precise to only a limited number of digits.  Also, it's stored base 2, and we think mostly in base 10, and some numbers that have a finite expression in base 10, don't have one in base 2, and vice versa.

So you should:

1. Never compare a floating point value for equality to another. 
   Instead, subtract them, take the absolute value, and compare that
   result to a small positive number like 1e-8.
2. Round your floating point values to a palatable number of places
   after the decimal point, using string formatting or the
   http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round function.

You can use the decimal module to get caller-specified precision.  Or if you have rational values, you can use the fractions module.

Comment: FYI your "vice versa" assertion is wrong. Every base 2 number has a finite representation in base 10, although the number of digits required may be surprisingly large - it is equal to the number of bits.